# Problema CSS en Wordpress con Divi Builder

Tags: css, wordpress

> Estoy haciendo la web https://flipashowroom.com.ar y tengo un problema en la navegación móvil.
> El menú secundario (de fondo negro que incluye las categorías de los productos) se muestra bien en todas las partes del sitio excepto en la tienda.

En el CSS personalizado tengo lo siguiente (para celulares):

> Las modificaciones son para eliminar el menú hamburguesa, y en su lugar dejé un menú que se desliza horizontalmente.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

     /* Muestro el menú secundario, lo que originalmente se ve en monitores y el breakpoint reemplaza por la hamburguesa */
     #menuDos .et_pb_menu__menu {
         display: block;  
      }

     /* Oculto los iconos de busqueda, tienda y menu hamburguesa */
     #menuDos .et_mobile_nav_menu, #menuDos .et_pb_menu__icon  {
         display: none !important;
      }



            /* Le doy al nav la propiedad nowrap para que quede en una sola linea */
           #menu-categorias {
             margin-left: 33em !important;
             display: flex;
             flex-wrap:nowrap;

           }

           /* Le doy overflow x al elemento padre del nav */
           #menuDos .et_pb_menu__wrap{
              overflow-x: auto !important;

             }

          /* escondo el scroll del menu*/
          #menuDos .et_pb_menu__wrap::-webkit-scrollbar {
           display: none;  /* Ocultar scroll */
                }

        }
```

> Me sucede que, cuando entro a la TIENDA (siempre estamos hablando de la navegacion movil, que es cuando se aplica el css de arriba) el menú desaparece. Si yo al bloque

```
 #menuDos .et_pb_menu__menu {
         display: block;  
      }
```

> Lo reemplazo por

```
  #menuDos .et_pb_menu__menu {
         display: none;  
      }
```

> tengo el mismo problema en todas las paginas. Es decir, sucede algo como si en la pagina de la tienda se aplicara `display:none` en ese elemento.

No puedo encontrar de donde viene el problema para modificar el comportamiento. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Recomiendo ver el sitio con el inspector del navegador, donde el problema se aprecia correctamente (Al menos desde chrome)

Comment: La solucion estaba en poner ``!important``, como wordpress usa multiples estilos css a veces se aplican propiedades que no esperamos.